# Unable to extract zip files using Java for zip64 type

Tags: java, compression, zip, zipinputstream

I am using following function to extract zip files in Java

```
public static List<String> unzipFiles(File zipFile, File targetDirectory) {
    List<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFile);
        zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                fileInputStream));
        ZipEntry zipEntry;
        int count = 0;
        while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            log.debug("Extracting File Name :: " + zipEntry);
            count++;
            int length;
            byte data[] = new byte[bufferGlb];
            String fileName = zipEntry.getName();
            File opFile = new File(targetDirectory, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(opFile);
            dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, bufferGlb);
            while ((length = zipInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferGlb)) != -1) {
                dest.write(data, 0, length);
            }
            dest.flush();
            files.add(fileName);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        }
        log.debug("Total " + count + " Files Unziped Successfully ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occured in unzipping the file " + zipFile, e);
}
```

}

This works totally fine for normal zip files.
But for certain zip files using zip64 format I am getting the below exception:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 21504 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:196)
```

Could someone please help me out with how to extract zip64 files.

Comment: Use some third-party library that supports it.

Comment: I have trying with jdk 1.7 and its giving this exception: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 21504 bytes) at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384) at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:196)